# Why did not I find all the solutions to this equation? $\sin{3x}+\cos{2x}-\sin{x}=1$

Tags: trigonometry

$x$ needs to be in $[0,\pi]$

What I tried

$\sin{3x}+\cos{2x}-\sin{x}=1$

$\sin{3x}-\sin{x}=1-\cos{2x}$

$2\sin{x}\cos{2x}=1-(\cos^2{x}-\sin^2{x})$

$2\sin{x}\cos{2x}=\sin^2{x}+\cos^2{x}-\cos^2{x}+\sin^2{x}$

$2\sin{x}\cos{2x}=2\sin^2{x}$

$\cos{2x}=\sin{x}$

$\cos{2x}=\cos{\dfrac{\pi}{2}-x}~~\Longrightarrow~~2x=\dfrac{\pi}{2}-x+2k\pi~~\lor~~2x=x-\dfrac{\pi}{2}+2k\pi$

$x=\dfrac{\pi}{6}+\dfrac{2k\pi}{3}~~~~(k\in\mathbb{Z})~~(1)~\lor~x=-\dfrac{\pi}{2}+2k\pi~~~~(k\in\mathbb{Z})~~(2)$

$(1):~~k=0~\Longrightarrow~x=\dfrac{\pi}{6},~~~~~~k=1~\Longrightarrow~x=\dfrac{5\pi}{6}$

But $0$ and $\pi$ are solutions too. Why did not I find $0$ and $\pi$?

Comment: you simplified $\sin x=0$

Comment: Did you divide by something that may have been equal to 0?  ... Hmmm, yes you divided by $\sin x$.  You need to consider that $\sin x=0$ may have solutions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your idea is correct except when you simplify $\sin x$ in

$$2\sin{x}\cos{2x}=2\sin^2{x}$$

A good way is:

$$2\sin{x}\cos{2x}-2\sin^2{x}=0$$

$$(\sin x)(2\cos{2x}-2\sin{x})=0$$

what give you

$$\sin x=0$$
or

$$2\cos{2x}-2\sin{x}=0$$

then, solve both equations and get the complete solution.

Comment: Valeu, Arnaldo! :D

Comment: I think you should explain why this is the 'right' way (ie because of $\sin x=0$ and dividing by $0$.

Comment: @Arnaldo I never said your word choice was bad, I was just suggesting and explanation of why dividing by $\sin x$ doesn't give you all the solutions...

Comment: @AndrewLi: my bad about the word, sorry! In the way I solved, I'm just using that $a.b=0$ then $a=0$ or $b=0$ which seems a very know result. More then that seems too much, but it is only my opinion.

Comment: @Vinícius: Sempre as ordens!